# python Threadsafe lock on loop

Tags: python, multithreading

Can someone please tell me if the following is threadsafe or not and if it isnt what must I do to make it so.

**Note:** this only a small sample, not sure if it runs.

```
TIMER = True
time_lock = threading.Lock()
def timing():
    while TIMER:
        # some logic will be here for now print time
        print time.time()

timer = threading.Thread(target=timing)
timer2 = threading.Thread(target=timing)
timer.start()
timer2.start()

while True:
    time_lock.aquire()
    if doSomeStuff():
        TIMER = True
    if otherThings():
        break
    time_lock.aquire()
    TIMER = False
    time_lock.release()

time_lock.aquire()
TIMER = False
time_lock.release()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on which implementation you are using, and what you are doing.

First, in the *de facto* standard implementation of python ("cpython"), only one thread is allowed to run at a time since some internals of the python interpreter aren't thread-safe. This is controlled by the Global Interpreter Lock (aka "GIL"). So in cpython, you don't really need extra locks at all; the GIL makes sure that only one thread at a time is running python code and possibly changing variables. This is a feature of the implementation, not of the language.

Second, if only *one thread writes* to a simple variable and *others only read it* you don't need a lock either, for obvious reasons. It is however up to you as the programmer to make sure that this is the case, and it is easy to make mistakes with that.

Even assinging to a simple variable might not need a lock. In python variables are more like labels used to refer to an object, rather than boxes where you can put something in. So simple assignments are atomic (in the sense that they cannot be interrupted halfway), as you can see when you look at the generated python bytecode:

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: x = 7

In [3]: def setx():
    global x
    x = 12
   ...:     

In [4]: dis.dis(setx)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (12)
              3 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The only code that changes x is the single `STORE_GLOBAL` opcode. So the variable is either changed or it isn't; there is no inconsistent state inbetween.

But if you e.g. want to test a variable for a certain value, and perform an action while that test still holds true, you do need a lock. Because another thread could have changed the variable just after you tested it.

Things like appending to a list or swapping variables are not atomic. But again in cpython these would be protected by the GIL. In other implementations you'd need a lock around such operations to protect against possible inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to signal your thread when to stop. Since this is a situation where only one thread writes to a shared variable and only once, you do not need a lock.

Locks are necessary when you are doing concurrent modification of a shared datastructure that cannot be read atomically.

Comment: what about when one could be writing and one could be reading at the same time? or would this never happen?

Comment: @aspect it doesn't matter -- since you're only changing a boolean False to True, there are no "interim" write states which the other thread coulds ee